# Braintree test Request.Params always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, braintree

I am implementing webhook test code and I am running into a problem.

After I POST a sample notification to my webhook listener the `Params` are not in the request:

**`Request.Params["bt_signature"]`**

**`Request.Params["bt_payload"]`**

So the listener fails.

Below is both my Post Webhook code and Listener code; I'm not sure if I'm using `gateway.WebhookTesting.SampleNotification` correctly.

### POST Test Webhook

```
private async Task PostTestNotification()
{
  try
  {
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50709/");

        var gateway = config.GetGateway();

        // Create sample notification
        Dictionary<String, String> sampleNotification = gateway.WebhookTesting.SampleNotification(
            WebhookKind.SUBSCRIPTION_CHARGED_SUCCESSFULLY, "sub_id_1234"
        );

        // Convert sample notification to JSON
        string payloadJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sampleNotification);

        // Create StringContent of json sample notificaiton
        var data = new StringContent(payloadJson);

        // data looks like this when debugging { "bt_payload":"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\n","bt_signature":"69r68j6hnzjpnq4j|508a7b4b3bbbe15c241c742331acfc5bacf37c54"}

        // POST
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("webhooks/accept", data);

        // RESPONSE
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
        {
            // SUCCESS CONTENT
            string resultJSON = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            // FAIL CONTENT
            dynamic problem = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```

### Webhook LISTENER

// webhooks/accept endpoint

```
public async Task<ActionResult> accept()
{
  try
  {
    var gateway = config.GetGateway();

    if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
       var bt_signature = Request.Params["bt_signature"]; <<<<<<< ALWAYS EMPTY >>>>>>>>>
       var bt_payload = Request.Params["bt_payload"]; <<<<<<< ALWAYS EMPTY >>>>>>>>>

        WebhookNotification webhookNotification = gateway.WebhookNotification.Parse(
            Request.Params["bt_signature"],
            Request.Params["bt_payload"]
            ); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< EXCEPTION WHEN HIT - Value cannot be null, Parameter name: Input >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>


        // ACTION Webhook 
        if (webhookNotification.Kind == WebhookKind.SUBSCRIPTION_CANCELED)
        {
            IsActive = false;
            await Logger.LogInsight("", "WEBHOOK: SUBSCRIPTION_CANCELED " + webhookNotification.Subscription.Id );
        }
        else if (webhookNotification.Kind == WebhookKind.SUBSCRIPTION_CHARGED_SUCCESSFULLY)
        {
            IsActive = true;
            await Logger.LogInsight("", "WEBHOOK: SUBSCRIPTION_CHARGED_SUCCESSFULLY " + webhookNotification.Subscription.Id);
        }

        // code ommitted for brevity, similar to above checking all 'kind' values 

     }     
   }
 }
```

Why are the Braintree Request Params empty?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the Webhook endpoint, the Braintree [sample code](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/parse/dotnet) is incorrect, it implies using MVC but developers need to use the Web Api for this, and the sample code will not work.

To get this working I left the Sample Notification POST above unchanged and created a new Webhook listener :

First create a class to receive the two braintree strings from the POST:

```
public class bt
{
    public string bt_payload { get; set; }
    public string bt_signature { get; set; }
}
```

And now create an empty Web Api 2 Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/webhooks/accept")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> accept(bt bt_lot)
    {
        var gateway = config.GetGateway();

        WebhookNotification webhookNotification = gateway.WebhookNotification.Parse(
            bt_lot.bt_signature,
            bt_lot.bt_payload
            );

        if (webhookNotification.Kind == WebhookKind.SUBSCRIPTION_CANCELED)
        {
            // take your action here...
        }
```

Im posting all my experiences with Braintree here on SO as there isn't a great deal of help here and I hope it helps others.

I have to say the Braintree Help staff are excellent and always answer questions with very detailed answers that 95% of the time resolved any issues I had, but this issue had me scratching my head as their example didn't work and the help staff assumed like me that the code should work.

Comment: I just fumbled my way through this in 2022.  As far as I can see, the Braintree docs are still misleading and this answer is the way to go.